# Network Error : Windows Cannot access on Ext2Fsd ext3 drive

Tags: windows-7, permissions, ext3

Unable to execute exe files from ext3 drive form Windows7 64 bit

giving error :Network Error : Windows Cannot access

Error code :0x800704b3

PS: Creating editing copying everything else works perfectly from this drive

Comment: its amazing that anything works. Windows doesn't understand EXT partitions. Can you tell us how you're able to even create/copy/edit?

Comment: I installed Ext2Fsd drivers to enable access to ext3 drive on Windows7

Comment: In Linux, when you mount a partition you can mount it with `noexec` which disallows executing anything on that partition. Perhaps this Windows driver has a similar feature?

Answer (score 3):

- If you are using **ext2fsd** with ext3, you need to start the **Webclient** service if you want to be able to execute files by double clicking:

  Go to **start**, right click **Computer**
  and click on **Manage**. The **Computer Management** window should appear. In
  the console tree box at the left, click on **Services and Applications**,
  then click on **Services**. A list of services should appear. Scroll down
  until you find **WebClient**. Right click it and click on **Properties**.
  Under the **General** tab click on **Start**. If you want to have the service
  start automatically as part of the Windows boot process, then set the
  **Startup** type to **Automatic**.
- If you don't want to have the **WebClient** service running, but still want to execute your file, then you can do that from the **Command Prompt**:

  Go to **start**, and in the search box type **cmd**. A **Command Prompt** will appear where you can navigate to your executable file. Type it's name to execute it.